# Flagging questions with details only in comments

Tags: discussion

There are many, many, many questions nowadays that are far from being complete and most of the times reading the comments reveal the missing pieces, as someone else asked for clarification and the OP added the details.

I usually add an extra comment like `Please also add the details to the question also`, if I don't have the time to edit the question, or if the details are spread among multiple comments and can't easily be "joined" within the question.

So, besides adding the comment,

1. Should I flag this kind of questions as unclear or too broad? Will this help the OP understand that they need to include all relevant details into the question?
2. Or should I down-vote the question? This would imply revisiting it later and removing my down-vote if the user has indeed updated the question.
3. Or should I leave it as is, further users that stumble upon this question will flag it appropriately if the user didn't edit the question?

For #3, If I stumble upon a question that has an accepted answer, but it's still incomplete as the asker didn't trouble to edit the question once he got the desired answer, is it OK to flag it (again if I don't have the time to extract the relevant pieces from the comment and add them to the question)?

Comment: Another option would be to edit the question to make it more clear, if you think that you have understood it properly.

Comment: @user000001: this is my first option, my question is how to proceed when I don't have the time to edit it

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Some of those questions are more of a "work in progress"; that is, some kind soul has elected to pry more information out of the OP and the OP is dutifully supplying it...in the comments section.

Someone then needs to encourage the OP to put the relevant missing details in the question instead.

In those scenarios, **always flag the question for the condition that you first observe it.** If you believe that the question is incomplete even though there may be a handful of clarifying remarks, then don't feel bad about flagging/voting to close.  It may be the case that someone comes along and adds those details into the question later; at that point, it'd be nice to remove the close vote.

For your point #2, you're free to use your votes however you wish, but I'd say only downvote if it's not useful or unclear or not well researched.

Comment: And if there _is_ enough information, it just needs to be edited into the question?

Comment: Yep, that seems like a reasonable thing to do.